# Mongo: query to fetch distinct data per day for last 30 days

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a requirement in my mongo database, to fetch Distinct list of jobs by day for last 30 days. The collection has followin 2 columns (apart from others)

jobType string
jobUploadDate string

I am new to this and I am stumped since the jobUploadDate is a string and not Date, so the comparison is even harder. I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.collectionName.distinct( "jobType " ).find({'jobUploadDate' : {{ $lte: jobUploadDate}}})
```

Comment: > db.jobs.distinct( "jobType" ).find({'jobUploadDate' : {{ $gte: jobUploadDate}}})

2016-09-26T16:21:28.958-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:55

Can $lte work on strings?

Comment: You can convert the string into Date while doing the query with new ISODate(...) and then try

Comment: share you collection data here so that it will help us to build the query faster